# Association in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, mongoid

I have three models, Employee, Job, LeaveDay. like below:

```
class Employee
 field :name
 belongs_to :job
end
class Job
 field :job_title
 has_many :employees
 has_many :leave_days
end
class LeaveDay
 belongs_to :job    
 field :no_of_leave_days
end
```

I want to establish an relationship in which I want to track `no_of_leave_days` of employee related to their job. How is it possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with Mongoid. You may read [here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html) more about relations in mongoid.

It's very easy example. Hope it'll help.

This is models definition:

```
class Employee
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  belongs_to :job
end

class Job
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :job_title
  has_many :employees
  embeds_many :leave_days
end

class LeaveDay
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :job
  field :no_of_leave_days
end
```

And example of usage:

```
pry(main)> j = Job.create(job_title: "Test Job")
=> #<Job _id: 510633e0784931179a000001, _type: nil, job_title: "Test Job">
pry(main)> LeaveDay.create(job: j, no_of_leave_days: 1)
=> #<LeaveDay _id: 5106348f784931179a000002, _type: nil, no_of_leave_days: 1>
pry(main)> LeaveDay.create(job: j, no_of_leave_days: 2)
=> #<LeaveDay _id: 51063687784931179a000003, _type: nil, no_of_leave_days: 2>
pry(main)> LeaveDay.create(job: j, no_of_leave_days: 3)
=> #<LeaveDay _id: 51063689784931179a000004, _type: nil, no_of_leave_days: 3>
pry(main)> Job.first.leave_days.map(&:no_of_leave_days)
=> [1, 2, 3]
pry(main)> Employee.create(name: 'Employee name', job: Job.first)
=> #<Employee _id: 510637cf784931179a000005, _type: nil, name: "Employee name", job_id:    "510633e0784931179a000001">
pry(main)> Employee.first.job.leave_days.map(&:no_of_leave_days)
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I tried but I have no ideas how to track no_of_leave_days in controller.

Comment: I've edited my answer and provided simple example. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

i think u need to add 'belongs_to: employee' in LeaveDay and 'has_many: leave_days' in Employee. so, @emp.leave_days will get u all the leave for all the jobs of a particular employee. similarly, @emp.job.leave_days will return the leave_days for the current job of the  cuttent employee.